# Tablix headers not repeating in SSRS 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssrs-2008

I have created a new report & add a table to it. When I select "Tablix Properties" and check on Columns Headers -> "Repeat Cheader columns on each page" the header columns do not repeat on each page. I also tried "Repeat header rows on each page". "Add page break before" seems to work ok. I am using VS 2008 9.0.30729.1 SP

I also tried deploying but it still does not work on the deployed version.

Interestingly, reports migrated from 2005 & unchanged seem to be ok.

Any ideas? Am I not setting something up properly?

Comment: What is your InteractiveSize Height property set to? If it is 0 that could cause this problem. It is usually 8.5in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the grouping section there is a pull-down that will let you switch to Advanced Mode.  Click that.  Once you've got Advanced mode activated you will see a number of (Static) objects show up in your groups -- these are your headers.

Highlight the static row above =(Details) in the Row groups, in the properties pane for that static group is an option for RepeatOnNewPage; setting that to true will repeat your headers.

[Here](http://www.analyticsby.me/2009/07/header-row-does-not-repeat-on.html) is the blog post from where I found this.